# Python Requests can make post locally but not in AWS ECS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, amazon-ecs

I am currently working on a project where I am attempting to hit a 3rd party API with a post request. To do this I am using the Requests library. When I run the code locally, the code executes fine. When I run the code in AWS ECS FARGATE I get the following error:

> Max retries exceeded with url:  (caused by SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')"

So clearly this is something to do with the ssl cert, but what? My code is just a basic

```
requests.post(url, cookies, headers, data, timeout, verify)
```

I have tried setting verify param to false.

I have tried installing the extra security components with requests using pip install requests[security]. This resulted in the longer more detailed error shown above but it was still the same error at it's core.

I have tried using the requests.session instead of a basic request. All produce the same result.

I have also ensured the security outbound protocol is open. I am just very confused as to why it's working locally and not ecs.

Any input is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: By default port 443 is disabled in AWS ecs. Have you enabled?

Comment: Yeah we did! But I found the solution. It ended up being a redirect on the api side which was not whitelisted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with our firewall whitelist and the fact that the third party API was using a redirect behind the scenes. The redirect was causing our connection to be severed because it was going to a non-whitelisted domain.